# Connecting table and feature class in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, esri-geodatabase

I have a polygon feature class inside of my geodatabase, and I want to attach attributes from some tables that resides in a separate database. Is there any way to do this that would maintain the relationship?

I have it working with joins, but that doesn't keep the relationship inside of the feature class.

Comment: If they are in completely different workspaces/databases you cannot store it in a file geodatabase.  For a file geodatabase containing only half of the data you can only create joins and relates that are layer based.  I believe the Join can be saved either as part of a layer within a map or as part of a layer file.  I don't think a relate can be stored any way outside of a layer within an actual map.  SDE may have more options, but I don't have any experience with those possibilities.  If Views actually can somehow work with File Geodatabases I would like to know how to set that up.

Comment: You are right. I can export the data, and all of the attributes will come with it, and it will be saved as a feature class. But, I want to set up something that will be updated on the fly, so that I don't have to overwrite my feature class every time there is a change in one of the original tables.

Comment: Just FYI, after some testing I found that relates can actually be stored in a layer file if the relate set up pointed to the data source feature class/table directly.  If the Relate set up was created between two layers added to the same map, I believe you could only save that relate through a group layer that included both layers.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what database type are you using, it can be pretty easy to set up.

If it's an enterprise geodatabase, you can create a view to join the tables.

> CREATE VIEW view_name AS
>
> SELECT column_name(s)
>
> FROM table_name
>
> WHERE condition

If it's a personal or file geodatabase, views are not supported.

Comment: I don't think that will work. I am trying to use information that is generated into tables from our accounting software, so it's on a completely separate database. I will look into Views some more, but I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: Depending on permissions and setup it can. We have a view that is set up between two different databases. I will try to grab more details later today.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951320/create-view-across-multiple-databases  Though you may want to perform your own search on the type of databases you are using.